# most efficient method to load in list of data files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am loading in a list of data files. I perform some analysis on each file after which I merge it into a list with all the previous files, similar to  this example:

```
data_total = [];
for i=1:10
    data = load( strcat('data_num_', num2str(i), '.dat');

    %perform analysis on data....

    data_total = cat(1, data_total, data);
end
```

Is this the most efficient way of doing this? Or does MATLAB have some commands to make this process more efficient?

Comment: In my opinion there is nothing wrong with your method. If you want to improve your code efficiency you should probably stay focus on the analysis part.

Comment: If your analysis can be vectorized, and you have enough RAM, it could speed things up to first append the data, and then do the analysis. And in general: use the profiler to find out where most time is spend, and concentrate on that part.